# PHP JSON String escape Double Quotes inside value?

Tags: php, json, string, escaping, double-quotes

I'm getting a JSON string from an api like this :

```
{ "title":"Example string's with "special" characters" }
```

which is not json decodable by using json_decode (its output is null).

so I want to change it to something json decodable like :

```
{ "title":"Example string's with \"special\" characters" }
```

or

```
{ "title":"Example string's with 'special' characters" }
```

in order to make json_decode function work, what should I do ?

Comment: you should escape it in a proper way before to send it, if you have possibility to do it

Comment: And what if the API returns `{ "key": "foo","bar":"baz" }`. Should that be transformed into `{ "key": "foo", "bar": "baz" }` (where there are two keys: `key` and `bar`, with the values `foo` and `baz` repsectively), or should it be transformed into `{ "key": "foo\", \"bar\":\"baz" }` (1 key, `key`, with a value)? It's unclear how you want to transform this situation.

Comment: I cannot change the api because it's not mine. please help me on the matter of escaping string.

Comment: There is no good answer. The API is broken and does not return JSON. The API needs to be fixed. Badly. Get whoever is responsible to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since yesterday I was trying to solve this tricky problem, and after a lot of hair pulling I came up with this solution.

First let us clarify our assumptions.

- json string should be right formated.
- The keys and values are quoted with double quotation.

**Analyzing the problem:**

We know that json keys formated like this (,"keyString":) and json value is (:"valueString",)

**keyString**: is any sequence of characters except (:").

**valueString**: is any sequence of characters except (",).

Our goal is to escape quotations inside **valueString**, to achive that we need to separate keyStrings and valueStrings.

- But we have also a valid json format like this ("keyString":digit,) this will cause a problem because it breaks out assumption that says values always ended with (",)
- Another problem is having empty values like ("keyString":" ")

Now after analyzing the problem we can say

1. json keyString has (,") before it and (":) after it.
2. json valueString can have (:") before and (",) after **OR**
   (:) before and digit as a value then (,) after **OR**
   (:) followed by (" ") then (,)

**The solution:**
Using this facts the code will be

```
function escapeJsonValues($json_str){
  $patern = '~(?:,\s*"((?:.(?!"\s*:))+.)"\s*(?=\:))(?:\:\s*(?:(\d+)|("\s*")|(?:"((?!\s*")(?:.(?!"\s*,))+.)")))~';
  //remove { }
  $json_str = rtrim(trim(trim($json_str),'{'),'}');
  if(strlen($json_str)<5) {
    //not valid json string;
    return null;
  }
  //put , at the start nad the end of the string
  $json_str = ($json_str[strlen($json_str)-1] ===',') ?','.$json_str :','.$json_str.',';
  //strip all new lines from the string
  $json_str=preg_replace('~[\r\n\t]~','',$json_str); 

  preg_match_all($patern, $json_str, $matches);
  $json='{';
  for($i=0;$i<count($matches[0]);$i++){

        $json.='"'.$matches[1][$i].'":';
        //value is digit
        if(strlen($matches[2][$i])>0){
            $json.=$matches[2][$i].',';
        } 
        //no value
        elseif (strlen($matches[3][$i])>0) {
            $json.='"",';
        }
        //text, and now we can see if there is quotations it will be related to the text not json
        //so we can add slashes safely
        //also foreword slashes should be escaped 
        else{
            $json.='"'.str_replace(['\\','"' ],['/','\"'],$matches[4][$i]).'",';
        }
  }
  return trim(rtrim($json,','),',').'}';
}
```

**Note:** The code realizes white spaces.